# User@host in a SSH-RSA public key

Tags: ssh-keys, public-key, rsa

What role does the user@host that often appears at the end of a public ssh-rsa key play?  Is it necessary?  Does if serve any purpose in the authentication, or is it simply a record of who and where the key was created by for the information purposes (for a human reader)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's merely a comment. You can put anything you'd like there. Or nothing at all.

Most key generators put user@host there to help identify on what host the key was generated, and for which user.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted to know.  I assume the key is delimited from the comment with white space, and the keys are separated from each other with new lines?

Comment: Yes, correct on both counts.

Comment: `man authorized_keys` will explain you the fieldss yo'ure allowed to use : extra-parameters(command, from, etc) whitespace type-of-key(ssh-rsa,ssh-dsa) whitespace key whitespace comments.

Comment: @Kwaio I don't have that ManPage.

Comment: sorry, mine redirects to `man sshd`, then look for "AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT" chapter